# Why is Robocopy frequently crashing on Windows 8 systems?

Tags: windows-8, robocopy, chinese

Since years we are using Robocopy to replicate files between Servers around the world. Now we have Windows 8 64 BIT Servers in China to which we have to replicate some files. But with this OS we suddenenly face the following issue:

Robocopy is just crashing. So we used also other Tools like fastcopy.

But the result is always the same: The executable is just crashing.

To other Locations we are not facing this issue.

Has someone already faced a similar issue?

We already found [1]. But the mentioned solution is not solving our crashing issue.

Thanks for a hint.

Best Regards

Frank

[1] 
[1] https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6eba1f81-8666-42ce-9aaa-e9cf8814c64f/robocopy-problem-under-windows-8?forum=w8itprogeneral

Comment: check your disk for physical damage or filesystem corruption with `chkdsk -R`. if multiple copy programs are failing, then the issue is with the data, and if it is causing crashes then it is likely at the windows API layer (filesystem) or the hardware level.

Comment: The issue is reproducible on several PCs. We have no PC in China where it is working on Win8 64 Bit.

Comment: Have you tried RichCopy??